# Color filling by GDP in a map

Tags: map

I would like to have a tool where one can type in a minimum GDP level and then every country that has this minimum level gets filled with color.

Comment: Edit your post and add code of what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: Sorry total newbie. Don't know where to start!

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html

Comment: I would recommend looking first at just getting the functionality you want before adding complicated GUI elements. Try creating an association of `country -> GDP`, then you can use `Select` to choose countries above a certain threshold